# Помогите "разложить на атомы" exe - файл!

Tags: .net, декомпиляция

Мне нужны позарез исходники (ну или документация) по разложению экзешника на составляющие. А именно: есть экзешник, написанный на VC++.Net, и надо написать прогу (на VC++ 6.0 или на VC++.Net) , которая смогла бы "прочитав" его выдать файл (*.txt or *.htm), в котором будут выписаны все функции и классы, которые использовались в экзешнике.

Comment: Попробуйте утилиту nm из MinGW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте через .NET Reflector, или ILSpy

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет частично программа resource hacker (reshack), картинки и иконки можно вытащить, иногда текстовые файлы и бд.

Comment: Мне надо вытащить код